# Create a List from information present in a table

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I need to create a list composed only the headers and elements of the first row of a table (or a range) where the cross between the 2 is equals to X.
Also, I need to place a formula in the cells next to the list depending of what element is written in the line: =AVERAGE(1;2;3;4) if the element is an Event, =Sum(RelatedEvent) in case the Element is an Asset

```
I.E.
|\ \ \ \ |Event1|Event2|Event3|Event4|
| Asset1 |   x  |      |   x  |      |
| Asset2 |      |   x  |      |      |  
| Asset3 |      |   x  |   x  |      |  
| Asset4 |      |      |      |   x  |  
| Asset5 |   x  |   x  |      |   x  |
```

In this case, the type of result i want to generate is:

```
Asset1|      |=SUM(Event1;Event3)
      |Event1|      |=AVERAGE(1;2;3;4)
      |Event3|      |=AVERAGE(1;2;3;4)
Asset2|      |=SUM(Event2)
      |Event2|      |=AVERAGE(1;2;3;4)
Asset3|      |=SUM(Event2;Event3)
      |Event2|      |=AVERAGE(1;2;3;4)
      |Event3|      |=AVERAGE(1;2;3;4)
Asset4|      |=SUM(Event4)
      |Event4|      |=AVERAGE(1;2;3;4)
Asset5|      |=SUM(Event1;Event2;Event4)
      |Event1|      |=AVERAGE(1;2;3;4)
      |Event2|      |=AVERAGE(1;2;3;4)
      |Event4|      |=AVERAGE(1;2;3;4)
```

For this kind of task i would prefer to have a formula, if possible, but i would not mind using also a macro.

Thanks